# Cloudformation to Terraform conversion of Deployment Group

Tags: terraform

I am converting the following Cloudformation code to Terraform. I have converted the most of the following code except the first few lines upto TriggerConfigurations (Type, DependsOn, Properties):

**Cloudformation:**

```
CodeDeployDeploymentGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup'
    DependsOn:
      - CodeDeployApplication
      - CodeDeployRole
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref CodeDeployApplication
      ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt 
        - CodeDeployRole
        - Arn
      TriggerConfigurations:
        - TriggerEvents:
            - DeploymentStart
            - DeploymentSuccess
            - DeploymentFailure
            - DeploymentStop
            - DeploymentRollback
            - DeploymentReady
          TriggerName: SlackTarget
          TriggerTargetArn: !ImportValue 
            'Fn::Sub': '${EnvName}CDNotificationTopicARN'
      DeploymentGroupName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref AppName
          - CodeDeploymentGroup
      DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce
      DeploymentStyle:
        DeploymentOption: !Ref DGDeploymentOption
        DeploymentType: !Ref DGDeploymentType
```

**Terraform:**

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "CodeDeployDeploymentGroup" {
  app_name               = aws_codedeploy_app.example.name
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce"
  deployment_group_name  = "${var.AppName}-CodeDeploymentGroup"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.example.arn

    deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "${var.DGDeploymentOption}"
    deployment_type   = "${var.DGDeploymentType}"
  }

  trigger_configuration {
    trigger_events     = ["DeploymentStart","DeploymentSuccess","DeploymentFailure","DeploymentStop","DeploymentRollback","DeploymentReady"]
    trigger_name       = "SlackTarget"
    trigger_target_arn = ["${EnvName}CDNotificationTopicARN"]
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to convert these lines of code to terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I coded the properties as below:

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "CodeDeployDeploymentGroup" {
  app_name               = ${var.CodeDeployApplication}
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce"
  deployment_group_name  = "${var.AppName}-CodeDeploymentGroup"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.CodeDeployRole.arn
```

Let me know if this is right.